# How to println double in a readable format?

Tags: java, format, double

For example, I want to calculate this: 4,000,000.0 * 4; and I got this: 1.6E7. What should I do, to got this: 16,000,000.0?? Thx!!

Comment: I suggest you review and accept previous answers before expecting people to spend time answering your questions.

Comment: `1.6E7` is a readable format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use DecimalFormat as follows:

```
double d = 10000000.00;
DecimalFormat dfmt = new DecimalFormat(",000.0");

System.out.println(dfmt.format(d)); // will display 10,000,000.0
```

Comment: it's nice, thx! BUT itt will display 10 000 000,00. how could i reach, to display this: 10000000.00?? so not "," , just "."? if i write this: new DecimalFormat("000.0");, it will display this: 10000000,0

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [java.text.DecimalFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) class.

Answer (score 1):

Use NumberFormat or DecimalFormat http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html

Answer (score 1):

You can implement [`DecimalFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) or [`String.format("%.2f", someNumber)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29).